# How to create a TypeScript library

Tags: typescript

I work on multiple TypeScript projects. I have common TypeScript code that I'd like to consume for multiple projects. How do I do this?

I expected to find something like **TypeScript Library Project** in Visual Studio's *Add new project* window, but that does not exist.

Comment: My first thoughts is that in Typescript it is a d.ts file http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files

Comment: From reading that, I get the impression that d.ts is used to create a TypeScript façade over an existing JavaScript library. I don't think it can help me solve this problem. (Thanks for the link though, I learnt something new)

Comment: Here an other link : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/571

Comment: Thanks. I opened a similar issue in their new GitHub project.

Comment: My approach would be to maintain it in a single project, and use some kind of a build process (through Gulp or Grunt) to create js and.d.ts file that you would reuse and publish via a package manager like bower or npm or NuGet

Comment: Here's a relevant issue on the GitHub Project : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11