# Project Setup: Creating a Typescript library package for nodejs using npm and webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I want to create a library in Typescript that I can share via npm. Specifically, I want to use webpack to generate a js bundle along with a definition file to share the types with the js. So I'd have a tree of files like:

```
├── lib
│   ├── lib.d.ts
│   └── lib.min.js
├── test
...
├── ts
│   ├── errors
│   │   ├── CannotModifyAlteredObject.ts
│   ├── Lib.ts
│   ├── PostProcessors.ts
│   ├── Serializers.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── typings.json
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── README.md
└── webpack.lib.config.js
```

And all the types exported by `ts/Lib.ts` would be exported to a single `.d.ts` in the `lib` directory to sit next to the js bundle.

I've looked at the following questions/sources:

- [Writing npm modules in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928253/writing-npm-modules-in-typescript)
- [How to create a typescript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217451/how-to-create-a-typescript-library) ([and the question it duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233108/cross-project-references-between-two-projects))
- [This unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950769/how-to-create-a-typescript-library-which-has)
- [The offical typescript guide to creating packages](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)
- [This example typescript library project](https://github.com/basarat/ts-npm-module)
- [And another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372014/publishing-a-typescript-library-on-npm-exported-symbols-modules)

However, none of these provide an example using webpack. Being able to bundle everything you need to use the library (apart from the nodejs runtime) into a single file is pretty important for my use case, so webpack fits this role well. I'd like to be able to generate a `.d.ts` file that maps to what webpack creates. However, I want to avoid creating the `.d.ts` file manually - it should be possible to automatically extract the types without having manually created `.d.ts` files get out of sync with my source code. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Is there any progress on this? Did you find a way to do it? Microsoft has some tools such as @microsoft/api-extractor that I'm not sure are suitable with this use case.

Comment: @TeemuK I stopped working on the project. However, since then I have seen this which looks like it may help: https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle